# Repeating Popup IDs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am pulling data from MySQL database and displaying user posted content on the page. A UserPost consists of data from 2 tables, UserTable and PostTable.

When querying from both tables I have the correct information displayed until I click the edit button.  Then the queried data inside the popup always matches the first element of the query.  I believe this is because the popup has an ID.  I tried using PHP data to have multiple buttons with different IDs but I am still getting the same popup content correlating with the first queried data.  I have highlighted the lines in question with "<-- PROBLEM HERE**********************************"
Thank you.

**PHP Function Calling All User Posts**

```
function homePosts($conn) {
        $UserID = $_SESSION['UserID'];
        $userPostSQL = "SELECT * FROM PostTable WHERE UserID = ? AND SectionID = 1 ORDER BY Date DESC";
        $userPostSTMT = $conn->prepare($userPostSQL);
        $userPostSTMT->bind_param("s", $UserID);
        $userPostSTMT->execute();
        $userPostRESULT = $userPostSTMT->get_result();

        if (mysqli_num_rows($userPostRESULT) != 0) {
            // User Posts Exist
            while ($userPostROW = $userPostRESULT->fetch_assoc()) {

                $userInfoSQL = "SELECT UserName, ProfilePicture FROM UserTable WHERE UserID = ?";
                $userInfoSTMT = $conn->prepare($userInfoSQL);
                $userInfoSTMT->bind_param("s", $UserID);
                $userInfoSTMT->execute();
                $userInfoRESULT = $userInfoSTMT->get_result();
                
                if (mysqli_num_rows($userInfoRESULT) != 0) {
                    // User Info Exists
                    while ($userInfoROW = $userInfoRESULT->fetch_assoc()) {

                        $Date = $userPostROW['Date'];
                        $Text = $userPostROW['Text'];
                        $PostID = $userPostROW['PostID'];
                        $UserName = $userInfoROW['UserName'];
                        $ProfilePicture = $userInfoROW['ProfilePicture'];

                        echo '
                            <div class="popup" id="popup-'.$PostID.'">    <-- PROBLEM HERE $PostID remains the same throughout the loop**********************************
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
                                    <h1>Edit Post</h1>
                                    <p>'.$Text.'</p>
                                    <p>This Post ID keeps the value of the first loop iteration'.$PostID.'</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="postBox">
                                <img class="postprofilepicture" src="../profilepictures/'.$ProfilePicture.'">
                                <p class="postusername">'.$UserName.'<p>
                                <p class="posttime">'.date('M jS, Y h:ia',strtotime($Date)).'<p>
                                <p>'.$Text.'</p>
                                <p>This Post ID Changes through for every new row'.$PostID.'<p>
                                <br>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">···</button>
                                    <div Id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">                                        
                                        <a href="#View">View</a>
                                        <a href="#Like">Like</a>
                                        <a href="#Save">Save</a>
                                        <a href="../editpost">Edit</a>
                                        <button onclick="togglePopup()">Popup</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <script>
                                function togglePopup(){
                                    document.getElementById("popup-'.$PostID.'").classList.toggle("active");    <-- PROBLEM HERE $PostID remains the same throughout the loop**********************************
                                }
                                function myFunction(e) {
                                    e.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show")
                                }

                                window.onclick = function(event) {
                                    if (!event.target.matches(".dropbtn")) {
                                        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                                        var i;
                                        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                                            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                                            if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
                                                openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                        ';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $userPostSTMT->free_result();
        $userPostSTMT->close();
        $userInfoSTMT->free_result();
        $userInfoSTMT->close();
    }
```

Comment: `function togglePopup`...is the real problem. You'll be creating multiple functions with the same name...clearly that's not allowed, javascript cannot tell them apart so it just picks one version and ignores the others. And you've hard coded an ID inside it. Pass the ID in as a parameter to the function instead, and only have one copy of it

Comment: Can you show an example of passing a parameter with the code above?  I've seen other examples but not specific to my issue.  Thank you

Comment: Well I imagine you'd write something like `onclick="togglePopup(\"popup-'.$PostID.'\")"`

Comment: That did not work, I am trying to figure this method out again.

Comment: Obviously you'd have to change the function accordingly too, did you do that? Or else what was the error?

Comment: The popup stopped appearing.  I tried <button onclick="togglePopup('.$PostID.')">Popup</button> and tried to reference it as a variable in js like this.  function togglePopup(PostID){
                                    document.getElementsByClassName("popup-+PostID+").classList.toggle("active");
                                }

Comment: I got it to work!  Just now, you helped me think through a solution!  
I am counting each row in a seperate variable and referencing that when calling the JS instead of the postid.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create a $Count variable that would assign a number for each post instead of using a random postid.  I could then call element by classname using the count number to call an array of all the divs with a specific class name.

$Count = 0;

```
<div class="popup" class="popup">
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup('.$PopCount.')">&times;</div>
                                    <h1>Edit Post</h1>
                                    <p>'.$Text.'</p>
                                    <p>This Post ID keeps the value of the first loop iteration'.$PostID.'</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="postBox">
                                <img class="postprofilepicture" src="../profilepictures/'.$ProfilePicture.'">
                                <p class="postusername">'.$UserName.'<p>
                                <p class="posttime">'.date('M jS, Y h:ia',strtotime($Date)).'<p>
                                <p>'.$Text.'</p>
                                <p>This Post ID Changes through for every new row'.$PostID.'<p>
                                <br>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">···</button>
                                    <div Id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">                                        
                                        <a href="#View">View</a>
                                        <a href="#Like">Like</a>
                                        <a href="#Show">Show</a>
                                        <a href="../editpost">Edit</a>
                                        <button onclick="togglePopup('.$PopCount.')">Popup</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <script>
                                function togglePopup(PopCount){
                                    document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[PopCount].classList.toggle("active");
                                }
                                function myFunction(e) {
                                    e.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show")
                                }

                                window.onclick = function(event) {
                                    if (!event.target.matches(".dropbtn")) {
                                        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                                        var i;
                                        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                                            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                                            if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
                                                openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                        ';
                        $PopCount++;
```